# Configuring Webpack not to bundle JS files together

Tags: webpack

I'm using Webpack to generate two sets of JS bundles, one that runs on the client and one that runs on the server. For the server, I would like Webpack not to bundle any files together like this:

```
source/
  entry-point.js  # requires component.js
  component.js

webpack-output-for-server/
  entry-point.js
  component.js
```

This way, when I run `webpack-output-for-server/entry-point.js` and potentially encounter an exception in `component.js`, the filename is preserved in the stack trace without relying on source maps. It's also just easier to view the generated source code instead of having to look through one large bundle.

Also in an Electron app I don't need to bundle JS files together because Electron defines a CommonJS implementation with `require()` the same way Node does. I'd still like to use Webpack for features like hot reloading but don't want it to bundle files together.

So, is there a way to tell Webpack not to bundle files, and to preserve their filenames?

Comment: Are you able to use other build tools as well, or strictly Webpack? It may be simpler to use Gulp to define one task that just copies the files over, and another that uses Webpack to create your bundle. They talk about it (briefly) in their documentation: https://webpack.github.io/docs/usage-with-gulp.html

Comment: Does my answer fit your use case?

Comment: You really should accept an answer if it solves your problem, or comment on why these solutions don't work for you. I think both @jared-dykstra and my answers should work for you.

Comment: @Mobius Both answers bundle files together. I actually want to know how to use all the other features of Webpack (e.g. HMR, file loaders, Webpack plugins) without bundling.

Comment: you might be able to do what you want with https://github.com/webpack/bundle-loader, but in general, you aren't going to be able to get webpack not to bundle. It **is** a bundler, the plugins just come along for the ride.

Answer (score 0):

The primary job of webpack is to bundle javascript, so if you want to maintain separate files, you should use `gulp` to copy the files over as suggested in the comment. However, webpack is capable of creating a `commonjs2` bundle which can be `require`'d in from the server. You would want to use this if your webpack configuration makes use of features like `babel` transforms, `css modules` or other `webpack` features that node doesn't natively understand.

In order to use this, you will need two webpack configurations, one for the server, and one for the client. In webpack this is achieved by exporting an array instead of an object.

for example:

```
var serverConfig = {
    entry : './source/entry-point',
    output : {
       path: './webpack-output-for-server/',
       library: 'your-app-name',
       libraryTarget: 'commonjs2',
       filename: 'your-app-name.js'
    },
    module : {
      ...
    }
};

var browserConfig = {
    entry : './source/entry-point',
    output : {
       path: './public/',
       filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    module : {
      ...
    }
};

module.exports = [
    serverConfig,
    browserConfig,
];
```

This will output two copies of your application, one will be bundled for the browser, but the other will be bundled as a self-contained `commonjs2` module which can be used by node. I have never tried to use this with Electron, but it would probably work.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with the answer provided by Mobius.  However, I encourage you to take a look at some of the popular template projects available on GitHub, including https://github.com/RickWong/react-isomorphic-starterkit  This particular template is very popular and has a lot of activity.

Webpack configuration is in the [configs](https://github.com/RickWong/react-isomorphic-starterkit/tree/master/configs) folder.  What they have done is create two separate configurations in two folders, and they are built simultaneously via scripts defined in package.json

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "forever --minUptime 1000 --spinSleepTime 1000 -c \"node --harmony\" ./dist/server.js",
  "build-server": "webpack --colors --display-error-details --config configs/webpack.server.js",
  "build-client": "webpack --colors --display-error-details --config configs/webpack.client.js",
  "build": "concurrently \"npm run build-server\" \"npm run build-client\"",
  "watch-server": "webpack --watch --verbose --colors --display-error-details --config configs/webpack.server-watch.js",
  "watch-server-start": "node node_modules/just-wait --pattern \"dist/*.js\" && npm run start",
  "watch-client": "webpack-dev-server --config configs/webpack.client-watch.js",
  "watch": "concurrently --kill-others \"npm run watch-server-start\" \"npm run watch-server\" \"npm run watch-client\""
}
```

In addition to the Client and Server script bundles, you'll find a wealth of other features in this template which really help development.  The key script is `npm run watch` which will run the development server so you can see changes as they are made.